# How can I keep the event waiting in the promise until it runs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In the process of sending character authentication to firebase.

code flow is...

1. User enters phone number and clicks button
2. Send the value to the server and send the authentication code in text
3. User enters authentication code and clicks button
4. authentication code value discrimination

In the second step, pressing the button will execute the `signIn()` i.e. the code.

```
 const signIn = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileNum, appVerifier)
      .then(function(confirmationResult) {

        //start

        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;

        confirmationResult
          .confirm(authCode)
          .then(function(result) {
            var user = result.user;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
          });

        //end
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

At this point, the part from `start` to `end` must be executed after step 3 (after the button event).

The `end` of the `start` has to wait for the button event to take place.

How can I do this?

Comment: You  can move the `//end` part inside `.then` of the inner call.

Comment: @Jai But can I only allow then to run when I click on a button?

Comment: It looks like you want to pause the execution inside. `confirm` call can pause it.

Comment: @Jai authCode is a value that the user must enter and cannot be determined whether it exists.Must only be executed when a button event is pressed. Is there something I'm mistaken about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do too much without the user being involved. The `signInWithPhoneNumber` Promise should resolve to showing the confirmation request page, and stop. It's done. The next step is up to the user submitting the confirmation number.

So, it looks like

1. Event handler 1 submits the phone number, then resolves to present confirmation entry screen
2. Event handler 2 submits the confirmation number to the authentication function, then resolves to update the user and present the welcome screen.

Promises are useful for managing computer processes, not user processes. You can't use a Promise to wait for a user. You need to provide an event handler they can trigger to continue the next step of the process.

Comment: Thanks you! Michael Landis.

I'm solved this issue!

Comment: Great! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

move the next code to another function :

```
confirmationResult
          .confirm(authCode)
          .then(function(result) {
            var user = result.user;
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
          });
```

and call the above function inside onClick of step 3

Answer (score 0):

You should shift the auth code confirmation to the left in the promise chain, so it's all done in sequence and you can execute code once both promises are done, like so:

```
    const signIn = () => {
        auth
          .signInWithPhoneNumber(mobileNum, appVerifier)
          .then(function(confirmationResult) {
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            return confirmationResult.confirm(authCode);
          })
          .then(function(result) {
            var user = result.user;
            // end here, auth code has been confirmed and you have access to user
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            // this will catch errors in either "signInWithPhoneNumber" or "confirmationResult.confirm"
            console.log(error);
          });
      };
```

Comment: However, this code will run to the very end once the second phase is completed and cannot proceed to the third stage. All I want is that the code from start to end is executed only when the button is clicked. Am I saying something wrong? I am sorry for my poor English.